# Checking Existence of file with Terminal

Tags: windows, ssh

Hi i'm working a course on node.js and the mentor uses Mac but my OS is Windows.
i tried to check existence of SSH file on my system with this command :

```
dir -al ~/.ssh
```

but couldn't get it to work.also searched here and google for it.
also he used `ls -a` at some point but

```
dir -a
```

did not worked either.

**So 1-How can i check if there is a SSH file on my windows OS?
and 2-what's the proper command for `ls -a` on windows**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `cygwin` if you want to use `ls`. You can ofcourse use for similar things also the `dir` command, but you need to check what is the syntax, for example [here](http://web.csulb.edu/~murdock/dir.html). Windows has different concept of hidden files, so you should probably use just:

```
dir .ssh
```

> So 1-How can i check if there is a SSH file on my windows OS?

No. It is not, if you mean `ssh` file, as a client application. It can be installed only under cygwin as already mentioned. Or you can use `putty` for basically the same tasks.

Comment: Thanks dir part worked but i'm still looking for second question and want to run it with windows commands

Comment: added the second part. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are going to use a wrapper class for a node.js So in this case you have to use .ssh file to create secure connection. Sad but true there is no .ssh file in Windows. Probably putty or ssh through cygwin will make your way as was mentioned above.

Comment: it's alright right now i want to find a command for 'ls -a' in windows